# How can i use my text-editor created in java to appear in "Open with" in Windows

Tags: java, windows, text, editor

I have created a Java Swing Text Editor.
I have created an EXE file of that application.
I want windows to automatically detect my application when it is installed and list it in "Open with" tab when any file is right-clicked.
Is there any java code for this ?

My question is similar to 
    [Have the ability to set Java application as default file opener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473762/have-the-ability-to-set-java-application-as-default-file-opener)

But the question has not been answered properly there .

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Java, but it's more a Windows problem

Here's how to add an app to the Open With tab:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/178066-open-add-program.html

The fact that you have built an EXE with your app, makes it a totally different question from the one you're quoting.

Comment: You dont understand. I dont want every user to manually add my app in open with tab. I want the app to appear in open with tab after my app has been installed in the user's pc.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Java or Windows.  You're looking for a tool that allows you to build an installation script for your Java application.

The [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is open source and free to use.  You can search for "Windows installer software" to find other installer products.

Comment: Can you provide me a detailed explanation as to how can i use NSIS for this.

Comment: I have already made a installer for my app using Excelsior Jet

Comment: Ok. After deep research i have finally made my app listed in Open with Tab...But now when i click open with(a text file) with my text-editor then it doesnt open the file. It only launchesmy text editor

Comment: Your text editor has to accept a command line parameter String which is the name of the text file.