# open and read random .txt with java aplication executable not knowing the rute of .txt

Tags: java, file, dump

I would like to know how I can open and display a .txt in a Java application . The .txt is associated with the application and when you click on it , the application opens, but the file does not get to be shown if not by passing a fixed route.

I've got to show it but only if the .txt file is in the same directory as the jar file and run the application only if directly . The direct access from the .txt opens the application but nothing more .

I have this code , you see the path step them directly . I want you to take from the .txt has been clicked .

```
    FileReader f = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);

    String linea_cliente = b.readLine();
    StringTokenizer datos_cliente = new StringTokenizer(linea_cliente,";");
    while(datos_cliente.hasMoreTokens()){
        pedido.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        id_cliente.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        nom_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        dir_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        cp_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        loc_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        prov_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        pais_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
        obs_cli.setText(datos_cliente.nextToken());
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English . Thank You ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "run the application only if directly" and "direct access from the .txt"?

Comment: You are trying to display a .txt file but reading only line from file ? Was this your intention?

Comment: You might want to check out System properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html and see if you can find the root of the relative path you want from one of those

Comment: clicking on .txt , the application would open with. I need to get the path of the clicked .txt , wherever you file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileReader f = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
```

Implies that archivo.txt is a **relative path**. Relative meaning in relation to the current executable. It is an implied `.\archivo.txt`

You can place it in a sub directory and use a relative path again like `.\myfiles\textfiles\archivo.txt` where `.\` is the location of your jar.

If you want to input many different text files and you don't know where they will be then you can use arguments. From the command line it would look like:

```
> java jar myproj.jar C:\test\foo\archivo.txt
```

And to access it in `main()` use:

```
String filePath = args[0]
FileReader f = new FileReader(filePath);
```

If you want it to be portable accross many systems you'll need to take advantage of [environment variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) to get your base path and then attach the route to your .txt file to the base.

Sorry, it was a little unclear what you were asking for so I covered a few common cases, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: thanks , it is quite useful to me , but I can not use the console ,you must click directly double click on the .txt file and then the application opens with the contents of .txt

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632793/use-a-java-application-as-the-default-program-for-a-particular-file-type) then. It describes exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but the application runs for me , the problem is that I can not get the path of the .txt file that executes it.

Comment: Whenever possible, Java system properties should be used instead of environment variables.  From the [documentation for System.getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--): “When passing information to a Java subprocess, system properties are generally preferred over environment variables.”